# Passing generator expressions to any() and all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator-expression

I was just messing around in the Python interpreter and I came across some unexpected behavior.

```py
>>> bools = (True, True, True, False)
>>> all(bools)
False
>>> any(bools)
True
```

Ok, so far nothing out of the ordinary...

```py
>>> bools = (b for b in (True, True, True, False))
>>> all(bools)
False
>>> any(bools)
False
```

Here's where things start getting spooky. I figure this happens because the `all` function iterates over the generator expression, calling its `__next__` method and using up the values until it encounters one that is `False`. Here's some evidence to back that theory up:

```py
>>> bools = (b for b in (True, False, True, True))
>>> all(bools)
False
>>> any(bools)
True
```

I think the result is different because the `False` is not at the end, so there are still some unused values left in the generator. If you type

```py
>>> bools = (b for b in (True, False, True, True))
>>> all(bools)
False
>>> list(bools)
[True, True]
```

It seems like there are only 2 remaining values.

So, why exactly does this really happen? I'm sure there are many details that I'm missing.

Comment: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Just to elaborate on the correct answer: generators exhaust. When all values have been generated, it won't produce any more. Using the same generator twice, then, won't work as you may expect at first.

Comment: worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do/231855#231855

Comment: This is actually a very good question. I've never thought of this and now I've ran through some tests to understand this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour of [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) are documented in the official documentation.

From the pseudo-code:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

`all()` only consumes `True` elements, it terminates when it finds the first element that evaluates to `False`.

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

`any()` consumes only `False` elements, it terminates when it finds the first element that evaluates to `True`.

Note that generators are not reset to their initial position when passed around.
They stay at their current position unless more items are consumed. Hence,

```
>>> bools = (b for b in (True, False, True, True))
```

The following will consume the first two items. Since the second item is `False`, the iteration stops after that. This leaves the generator at a position after the second element.

```
>>> all(bools)
False
```

At this point the generator has `(True, True)` as the remaining values. You point that out correctly in your question. The following only consumes a single element.

```
>>> any(bools)
True
```

Note that there is still another `True` value obtainable
from the generator after calling `any()`.

And of course, if you call `list()` on a generator, all items from the generator are consumed and the generator will not yield any more items (it is "empty").

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @dhke. I like how you explain what is going on inside the functions.

Comment: @sam-pyt: Note that the pseudo code isn't mine, these are the actual explanations given in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 10):

The problem that you are having is that you are using the generator after it has produced all the values.

You can verify this by running the following code:

```
>>> bools = (b for b in (True, False, True, True))
>>> all(bools) # once the False is found it will stop producing values
True
>>> next(bools) # next value after False which is True
True
>>> next(bools) # next value after True which is True
True
>>> next(bools)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

This will work:

```
>>> bools = (b for b in (True, False, True, True))
>>> all(bools)
False
>>> bools = (b for b in (True, False, True, True))
>>> any(bools)
True
```

Comment: Nice catch — that can be really hard to see.

Comment: The first example doesn't produce an error, it prints `True`. I think if you change it to `bools = (b for b in (True, True, True, False)`, it will produce the given error.

Comment: This answer and the one by @dhke are both valid for different organization of the seeds for the generator

Comment: @samp-pyt, that is correct, I updated my answer just now.

Answer (score 3):

A couple things are at play here.

The first thing is that generators can run exactly once for each element they're given. Unlike lists, or tuples, or any other objects with a fixed state, generators know what the `__next__` value is, how to generate the value after that, and basically nothing else. When you call `next(generator)`, you get that next value, the generator figures out a new `__next__`, and it completely loses memory of the value you just obtained. In essence, *generators can't be used multiple times in a row*.

The second thing is how `all()`, `any()`, and `list()` work internally, especially vis-a-vis generators. `all()`'s implementation looks something like this, only more complicated:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if bool(element) is False:
            return False
    return True
```

That is, the `all()` function *short-circuits* when it first finds a non-truthy element (and `any()` does the same thing, except the reverse). This is to save on processing time - why process the rest of the iterable if just the first element is unacceptable? In the case of a generator (e.g. your last example), this means it consumes all elements up until it finds a `False`. The generator still has elements left, but since it's already yielded those first two, it will behave in the future as though they never existed.

`list()` is simpler, and just calls `next(generator)` until the generator stops producing values. This makes the generator give up *any values it hasn't yet consumed*.

So the explanation for your last example is that

1. You create a generator that will spit out the elements `True, False, True, True` in order
2. You call `all()` on that generator, and it consumes the first two elements of the generator before it terminates, having found a falsey value.
3. You call `list()` on that generator, and it consumes all remaining elements of the generator (that is, the last two) to create a list. It produces `[2, 2]`.

Comment: Ok, so it is what I suspected. Good to know, thank you for the answer.